# jQuery nested .parent() method not working on dynamic element, even with .delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="lessons_append_to">
    <div id="lesson_container">
        <div>
        ...
        <div id="delete_conatiner">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lesson_container">
        Same as first one
    </div>
    <div id="lesson_container">
        Same as first one
    </div>
</div>
```

All the `lesson_container` are dynamically generated.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).delegate('.delete', 'click', function(){
    if (!confirm("Do you really want to delete the lesson?")){
     return false;
    } else {
     var select = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent(); //It works and gets a #lesson_container
     console.log(select); //Returns selected object
     var selected = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();//This doesn't work and #lesson_append_to can't be selected
     console.log(selected); //Returns undefined
    }
 });
```

Can you help me with a clue? Or tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `.delegate()` is depreciated since version 3.0. Use `.on()`. Details [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: What jquery version are you using?

Comment: consider using closest('selector') to select parent

Comment: id should be unique, you can't have thrice the dame id.

Comment: are you sure your lesson-containers are dynamically added where you think they are ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `JQuery` i suggest using the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) funcrion

You JavaScript would look like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    if (!confirm("Do you really want to delete the lesson?")){
     return false;
    } else {
     var select = jQuery(this).closest( "#lesson_container" ); 
     console.log(select); 
     var selected = jQuery(this).closest( "#lesson_append_to" );
     console.log(selected);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Still `closest()` on `#lesson_append_to` returns undefined.